# How to check if DateTimeField is (not) empty in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Widget DateTimeField which should not be empty while sending the data in form.

I tried using validator and comparing it with null but it does not work.

```
                    DateTimeField(
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (!value.isAfter(DateTime.now())) {
                            return 'Date cannot be in past';
                          }
                          if (value == null) {
                            return 'Date cannot be empty';
                          }
                          return null;
                        }
                      ),
```

Does anyone know how to check if this field contains a value?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value is null ***before*** other stuff, not ***after***.

```
DateTimeField(
                        validator: (value) {
                         if (value == null) {
                            return 'Date cannot be empty';
                          }
                          if (!value.isAfter(DateTime.now())) {
                            return 'Date cannot be in past';
                          }
                          return null;
                        }
                      ),
```